# TestCafe in Jenkins is unable to establish browser connection

Tags: google-chrome, jenkins, automation, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a set up in jenkins which uses a node docker image in the agent, installs chrome and testcafe in the jenkinsfile, which is verified by running testcafe -b in the jenkinsfile and seeing chrome as an available browser.  However every time i use npm test exactly as i would in my local machine i get....

```
Error: Unable to establish one 
or more of the specified browser connections. This can be caused by 
network issues or remote device failure.
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here, i don't know if it's relevant that i set up my own test runner as per the documented instructions, which is why I'm not using the testcafe docker container.
here is my jenkinsfile...

```
pipeline {
agent {
    docker { image 'node:8.11-jessie' }
}
stages {
    stage('Node check'){
        steps {
            sh 'node -v'
        }
    }
    stage('Install Chrome') {
        steps {
            sh 'apt-get update'
            sh 'apt-get install -y gconf-service libasound2 libappindicator3-1 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget'
            sh 'rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*'
            sh 'wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb'
            sh 'dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb'
        }
    }
    stage('Npm installs') {
        steps {
            sh 'npm install -g testcafe testcafe-reporter-xunit'
            sh 'npm install'
        }
    }
    stage('browsers') {
        steps {
            sh 'testcafe -b'
        }
    }
    stage('Test test'){
        steps{
            sh 'npm test -- --env=gamma --browsers=chrome:headless'
        }
    }
}
post {
    always {
        junit '**/testcafe/res.xml'
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Nvm, i should be using the --no-sandbox chrome flag, its in the testcafe docs but quite hard to find and not fully explained.  For my instance I created my own flag `--noSandbox` that in my test runner code adds the `--no-sandbox`flag to the argument passed to the `.browsers()` function if it contains "chrome" or "chromium"

Comment: i've used this flag and I still get the error in jenkins / docker